# Points for comments

Tags: feature-request

I notice that Server Fault awards users two rep points for upvoted comments.  Should we implement the same feature?  I don't know how many other sites have the same feature, so I don't know if SF is the norm or we are.

**EDIT**

Encouraging useful comments seems like a good idea.  Often useful information is contained in them.

Comment: You should accept the answer, so that it doesn't keep popping up. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upvotes on comments do not add reputation anywhere on Stack Exchange network. The proposal to do so was poorly received and officially declined: [Reputation for comment votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189666/reputation-for-comment-votes)

You got 2 points [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/952393/google-cloud-vpn-issue-cisco-asa-cryptomap) because your suggested edit was approved, not because your comment was upvoted.

Comment: Oh.  Well then.  I withdraw the request.

Comment: This is outrages, i was so happy when i read this question.